# Nginx + Wordpress + Roots Rewrite URL Parameters

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to have Wordpress handle custom parameters from a rewritten URL. Using the below rewrite, I can do a print_r($_REQUEST) and see that a URL such as spots.com/plans/ky/lexington/ actually shows state=ky and city=lexington, but it is on the 404.php, instead of actually posting the values to spots.com/plans/.

For the rewrite, I have tried doing spots.com/?pagename=plans&state=$1&city=$2, but in that case, it just dumps me onto spots.com/plans without anything being populated. I have gotten a URL such as spots.com/plans/41005/ to post correctly (using last rather than break), but the second argument is tripping me up to the tune of 10 or so hours of nginx config and filters in functions.php.

```
/plans/?state=ky&city=lexington
```

populates the page correctly, but is ugly and onerous.

Below is the most recent Nginx config I've used, which results in

```
Array ( [q] => /plans/ [state] => ky [city] => burlington )
```

being shown on the 404 page I'm redirected to.

```
# serve static files directly
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|html|txt)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires           max;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; #q=$uri isn't needed, just using it for troubleshooting?
    }

#Pass off php pages to php-fpm
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

rewrite ^/plans/([^.]*)/([^.]*)/$ /plans/?state=$1&city=$2 break;
rewrite ^/plans/([^.]*)/([^.]*)$ /plans/?state=$1&city=$2 break;
```

Since the values seem to be passing through Nginx, should I be looking more at

```
 add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
    function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
    {
    $state[] = 'state';
    $city[] = 'city';
    $qvars = $city[] + $state;
    return $qvars;
    }
```

or am I way out in left field?

Comment: Have you aware that after `rewrite` there is no `.php` in the url? thus, it will not pass to the `fastcgi` location to handle php?

Comment: Wordpress routes everything through index.php, then looks through its own set of internal rewrites? With this setting, I'm not getting an Nginx 404 or server error. Wordpress is loading and showing the variables, but it seems to try loading /plans/ky/lexington instead of realizing that /ky/lexington are post values intended for /plans ?

Comment: No, in your nginx config, I see a typical location of `location ~ \.php$` that means request to nginx will only be transfer to the `fastcgi( cgi wrapper for executing php scripts)` only if the `uri( without the arguments, not url)` ended with a `.php` tail.